# How to initialize variable to avoid 'cannot read property <variable> undefined'?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interface

I am working on an angular application. I have a method in which I am trying to assign values to the variables from the data received from API call.
code

```
this.adminService.getConfigurations(input).subscribe(
    data => {
        this.data_Configuration = data[0];
        this.data_Configuration_e = data[1]     
        this.data_Configuration.forEach(itm => {
            itm.ApplicableDetails = []
            
            this.data_Configuration_e
                .filter(ent => ent.Id == itm.Id)
                .forEach(e => {itm.ApplicableDetails.push(e)});
                        
            itm.ApplicableLevel.FirstFl = itm.ApplicableDetails.some(e => e.Nm == 'First') ? 'Y' : 'N'             
            itm.ApplicableLevel.SecondFl = itm.ApplicableDetails.some(e => e.Nm == 'Second') ? 'Y' : 'N'
        });
```

My data_Configuration variable is defined from a interface

```
public data_Configuration : IConfiguraion[] = []

export interface IConfiguration {
  Id: string;
  Nm: string;
  ApplicableLevel?: IApplicableLevels;
  ApplicableDetails?: IDetails [];
}

export interface IApplicableLevels {
    FirstFl?: string;
    SecondFl?: string;
}
```

When I try to assign values to `FirstFl` using `itm.ApplicableLevel.FirstFl = itm.ApplicableDetails.some(e => e.Nm == 'First') ? 'Y' : 'N'`   line I get an error cannot property `FirstFl` of undefined. How or where should I initialize the value of `FirstFl` to avoid this error?

Comment: The error doesn't mean that `FirstFl` is undefined, it means that `itm.ApplicableLevel` is undefined. You'll probably want to insert `itm.ApplicableLevel = {};` before assigning to it.

Comment: The interface is called `IPrgmConfiguration` but the type definition is `IConfiguraion`. Which I assume is a typo while posting the question?

Comment: @MichaelD Yes that's a typo. edited

Comment: @ChrisG, why { } and not [ ], when to use { } over [ ]  ?

Comment: `{}` is an object with named properties, `[]` is an array with index numbered elements.

Comment: Here's a playground that reproduces the problem: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED2IbAOYCuUcYw2yA3gFDJoAmAXMgM5hSh4DcNyAcgLZNW7EFx4BBAA6SANsARwARjIgAZCADcIMgPxNUU2fKUr1Wmc261DchcogARCGDjALe5HBABPZAG0AXW4AXyoqUEhYRBQDaVsTNU1tZkoeWgAxYChWdN0hNg4rWmQAZQgEbDpcj2FCqlCqCpBWZGAwQTQsHHwiEjIQZABeSnomACIAC20ZTDGAGj4OsYB3TCgZOjHg7ioAel3W9oA6G2N7M20hym3w49O7UySZI8zssFyrsYAJadnOIA) (uncomment line 15 to fix)

Comment: use `itm.ApplicableLevel=itm.ApplicableLevel || {} as IApplicableLevels` before assign FirstFl. When we use interface, some like {} as IConfiguration, the variable has all the properties of the interface but they are `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it's a TS Lint error because the `itm.ApplicableLevel` isn't initialized yet. You could instead try to initialize the `ApplicableLevel` property with both it's sub-properties `FirstFl` and `SecondFl` as an object instead.

Also you could skip an additional level of iterations of the `data_Configuration_e` array by replacing the unnecessary `filter` with an `if` in the `forEach` loop.

Try the following

```js
this.data_Configuration.forEach(itm => {
  itm.ApplicableDetails = [];
  
  this.data_Configuration_e.forEach(e => {
    if (ent.Id == itm.Id) {
      itm.ApplicableDetails.push(e);
    }
  });

  itm.ApplicableLevel = <IApplicableLevels>{
    FirstFl: (itm.ApplicableDetails.some(e => e.Nm == 'First')) ? 'Y' : 'N',
    SecondFl: (itm.ApplicableDetails.some(e => e.Nm == 'Second')) ? 'Y' : 'N'
  };
});
```